# How to minimize an objective function with series of sums in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to minimzies the following optimization problem in MATLAB (sorry for the ugly form, but apparently I need more reputation to post images):

w* = argmin f(w)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(w_i(Cw)_i-w_j(Cw)_j)^2
s.t.
1^Transposed * w
0<=w<=leq1

w is a 1xn vector of weigths and C a nxn covariance matrix.

For now I`ve got this:

```
w0 = [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25];

Aeq = ones(1, port_size);
beq = 1;

lb = zeros(1, port_size);
ub = ones(1, port_size);

fun_rp = @(w) 
for i = 1:port_size
    for j = 1: port_size
        (w(1,i)*(C*w(1,i)')-w(1,j)*(C*w(1,j)'))^2;
    end
end
```

Then I want to put the variables into the fmincon function to solve the problem.

But somehow I receive an error that fun_rp is an undefined function or variable. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Best regards

Comment: These links may help you: [link1](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/288195-minimize-objective-function-with-sums) and [link2](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/166244-minimizing-an-objective-function)

Comment: Yes, they helped! Thank you very much!!